# eslint: linter.mjs:125309 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'sourceCode' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, version, eslint

I am upgrading from eslint 5 to 7.
Now when I have a file with simply a single digit
in it (say 3)
I get this error:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'sourceCode'
> of object '#<Object>' Occurred while linting <input>
>     at Function.assign (<anonymous>)
>     at runRules (linter.mjs:125309:17)
>     at Linter._verifyWithoutProcessors (linter.mjs:125690:32)
>     at Linter.verify (linter.mjs:125788:58)
>     at validator (eslint-lint.js:377:38)
>     at startLinting (lint.js:181:25)
>     at lint.js:238:43
```

I have removed all of the "removed rules" documented at eslint's website.
Overall eslint is working but there's a number of cases that it indicates an error when there shouldn't be one. This is the simplest of them.